# Display checkbox instead of image

Tags: html, css

I would like to display `checkbox` instead of image (image must be hidden in every row). Another problem is that `height` of the space reserved for the image must be same as image, but `width` must be 30px (height of the image is dynamic, so I don't know it). It would be ideal if checkbox is in the center of the space reserved for the image. Is it possible to do this?

[Here](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/mWyvMM?editors=1000) is example and code:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Image</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td><img src='http://i.imgur.com/cddKZVx.jpg'><input type='checkbox'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src='http://i.imgur.com/cddKZVx.jpg'><input type='checkbox'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src='http://i.imgur.com/cddKZVx.jpg'><input type='checkbox'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src='http://i.imgur.com/cddKZVx.jpg'><input type='checkbox'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src='http://i.imgur.com/cddKZVx.jpg'><input type='checkbox'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So why don't you use <input type="checkbox"> ?

Comment: Sorry, I can not understand what do you mean by image height must be kept? You want the height of a table cell must be the height of original image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MoazW/5xn9pxpd/2/)

CSS

```
img{
    /*opacity: 0; adjust the opacity to show or hide the img*/
    visibility: hidden;  /* @Marcos Silva */

}
.img_con{
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
input{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    bottom:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 100%
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <thead><th>Image</th></thead>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="img_con"><img src='http://i.imgur.com/cddKZVx.jpg'><input type='checkbox'></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="img_con"><img src='http://i.imgur.com/cddKZVx.jpg'><input type='checkbox'></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="img_con"><img src='http://i.imgur.com/cddKZVx.jpg'><input type='checkbox'></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="img_con"><img src='http://i.imgur.com/cddKZVx.jpg'><input type='checkbox'></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="img_con"><img src='http://i.imgur.com/cddKZVx.jpg'><input type='checkbox'></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same result if all DIV's are in the same cell?  only one row, one cell ?

Comment: the same css  @FrenkyB

Comment: If you find time and check my other question. It is not the same, because all elements are in the same cell, not in different rows.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/MoazW/sa694nvd/1/ or https://jsfiddle.net/MoazW/wjLguLkm/  ( Is it possible to achieve the same result if all DIV's are in the same cell? only one row, one cell ?) all divs in one <td> @FrenkyB

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want a CSS rule like that:

```css
    img {
      position: absolute;
      width: 30px;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead><th>Image</th></thead>
  <tr>
    <td><img src='http://i.imgur.com/cddKZVx.jpg'><input type='checkbox'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src='http://i.imgur.com/cddKZVx.jpg'><input type='checkbox'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src='http://i.imgur.com/cddKZVx.jpg'><input type='checkbox'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src='http://i.imgur.com/cddKZVx.jpg'><input type='checkbox'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src='http://i.imgur.com/cddKZVx.jpg'><input type='checkbox'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```